# SharePoint ReST API: Getting 403 while getting subsites of root site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, error, sharepoint-permissions

We are trying to perform `GET http://<site url>/_api/web/webs` using SAML Authentication.

User can access subsites through UI. But still getting 403 while accessing above API using ReST.

Kindly let us know how can we resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint you need to use is

`/_api/web/getsubwebsfilteredforcurrentuser(nwebtemplatefilter=-1,nconfigurationfilter=0)`

It will give you permission trimmed list of subsites

The `/_api/web/webs` endpoint only works for users with elevated permissions.

Reference - [Webs REST API reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn499819(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#bk_WebGetSubwebsFilteredForCurrentUser)

Comment: Thanks for quick response; We able to get subsites; But I guess $top and $skip filters are not working with this query; Do you know how to do this using getsubwebsfilteredforcurrentuser

Comment: Hmm, I think those parameters won't work for this endpoint.